# After copying Quill editor contents into hidden field, how to access value with flask request?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, quill

Trying to use Quill.js.  But cannot seem to retrieve contents of editor using flask request.

Here is the relevant HTML

```
    <form class='form-horizontal' method='POST' id="inputform"
        action="/page/update/{{ data._id }}">
         .
         .
         . 
        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="editor">
                {{ data.body | safe }}
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenArea" id="hiddenArea" >
        </div>
         .
         .
```

The script is

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var toolbarOptions = [
     .
     .
     .
    ];
    var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
        theme: 'snow',
        modules: {
            toolbar: toolbarOptions
        }
    });
    var form = document.getElementById('inputform');
    form.onsubmit = function() {
        // Populate hidden form on submit
        var hiddenBody = document.querySelector('hiddenArea');
        var html = document.querySelector('.ql-editor').innerHTML;
        hiddenBody.value = html;

        return true;
    }
});
</script>
```

Then I try to retrieve it with a flask routine containing

```
self.body = request.form.get('hiddenArea')
```

but this returns "" to self.body whereas other fields in the same routine that do not use the Quill editor work just fine.  Any pointers appreciated.

After using the console on the browser, I noticed that at the point of the error, the following message was displayed.

```
61e6245db30ee84ae9c9ee16:543 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')
at form.onsubmit (:8080/page/goto_edit/61e6245db30ee84ae9c9ee16?:543:30)
```

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From the code,

```
var form = document.getElementById('inputform');
form.onsubmit = function() {
// Populate hidden form on submit
var hiddenBody = document.querySelector('hiddenArea');
var html = document.querySelector('.ql-editor').innerHTML;
hiddenBody.value = html;
```

on line 4,

```
change var hiddenBody = document.querySelector('hiddenArea')
```

to

```
change var hiddenBody = document.getElementById('hiddenArea')
```

That did it for me.